# Detect byte objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do i detect `<class 'bytes'>` objects in Python?

I want something along the lines of

```
 if type(x) == bytes:
     doesomething(x)
```

Comment: @Fredrik: Do you even understand what `is` does?

Comment: Did you try the code you posted? It should work. But as the answer below notes, `is` would be preferred to `==`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
if type(x) is bytes
```

Or:

```
if isinstance(s, bytes)
```

Comment: the preferred form is `isinstance` - as it works with subclassing and "virtual" subclassing using ABCs